# Find List<T> second to last element

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to find the second to the last item in a list. One article came up with the search terms I used and they suggested getting the index of the last element then backing up one step. Is this really the way to do it....? Seems kinda kludgy / hard coded. Perhaps I'm being too paranoid??

```
int _lstItemIdx = List<MyObj>.IndexOf(List<MyObj>.Last());
int _sndLstItmIdx = (_lstItemIdx - 1);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
var result = myList[myList.Count-2];
```

Of course, you need appropriate exception handling in case your list doesn't have 2 elements.

And you can turn it into an extension method:

```
public static T SecondToLast<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    if (source.Count < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("The list does not have at least 2 elements");

    return source[source.Count - 2];
}
```

Comment: Well...I'm not as smart as you which is why you have over 3K points and I only have 400.

Comment: @user1278561 it's not about being smart, I've just done this exact thing before in another situation.

Comment: Well plus one for the extension method. Very nice touch!

Comment: Add generic parameter type after method name <T>.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad of course you are correct.  I'm shocked no one noticed that typo in almost 3 years