# How to find second last element from a List?

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<string>` like:

```
 List<String> lsRelation = new List<String>{"99","86","111","105"}.
```

Now i want to find the Number 111 that is the second to last string.

So I have tried:

```
String strSecondLast=lsrelation.Last() - 2;
```

which doesn't work. So how can i find the second to last element of a List using `Last()`.

Comment: What should be returned if there is just one item or no item at all?

Comment: @Caramiriel: what do you expect an array to return if you try  `arr[arr.Length]`? There is no alternative to an exception. Every value as `null` could be a valid value in the collection. So you couldn't distinguish between the case that the collection has less than two elements and the case that the element is actually `null`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: There are various ways to do this (exception, TryGet-pattern, null if out of range), though I just wanted to trigger the person to think about the possibility of having less than two items in the collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find List<T> second to last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412030/find-listt-second-to-last-element)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use:

```
if (lsRelation.Count >= 2)
    secLast = lsRelation[lsRelation.Count - 2];
```

Answer (score 12):

Starting with **C# 8.0** you can use [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index) to get access to elements relative to the end of sequence:

```cs
if (lsRelation.Count >= 2)
    secLast = lsRelation[^2];
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) for more information

Answer (score 11):

If you know that's an `IList<T>` which has an indexer:

```
string secondLast = null;
if (lsRelation.Count >= 2)
    secondLast = lsRelation[lsRelation.Count - 2];
```

You could create an extension like:

```
public static T SecondLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    IList<T> list = items as IList<T>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 1)
        {
            return list[count - 2];
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must contain at least two elements.", "items");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            return items.Reverse().Skip(1).First();
        } catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must contain at least two elements.", "items");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```
string secondLast = lsRelation.SecondLast();
```

Comment: Might want to check the list actually contains at least one item before trying `.First()`

Comment: @RGraham: Why? it will throw an exception for that case which is desired. What should i return instead? Every value i could return (as `default(T)`) could  potentially be a valid value which would even be worse than throwing a meaningful exception.

Comment: @RGraham: i have edited the answer to make the exception more explicit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ElementAt(list.Count - 2)`:

```
List<String> lsRelation = new List<String> { "99", "86", "111", "105" };
Console.WriteLine(lsRelation.ElementAt(lsRelation.Count - 2)); // 111
```

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of options for doing this. Just to mention one that I've not seen here yet:

```
List<string> lsRelation = new List<String>{"99","86","111","105"};
String strSecondLast = lsRelation.Skip(lsRelation.Count() - 2).First();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using `Last()`. Try this. You take the length of the list and subtract 2:

```
if (lsRelation.Count >= 2)
{
    var item = lsRelation[lsRelation.Count - 2];
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comment, here's an example using the `Last()` method, which would be ridiculous to use:

```
if (lsRelation.Count >= 2)
{
    var item = lsRelation.Last(x => x == lsRelation[lsRelation.Count - 2]);
}
```

Comment: *You can't do this using Last()* Not true, you can use the predicate overload for last and use the index to test if it is the last element before the given index....it just doesn't make any sense to do it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguous question - what if your list has only one element? what if your list is empty? what if your list is null?

the obvious answer to a `List` would be

```
var beforeLast = lsRelation[lsRelation.Count -2];
```

to cover all your edge cases, I would use

```
string beforeLast = null;
if (lsRelation != null && lsRelation.Count > 1)
   beforeLast = lsRelation[lsRelation.Count - 2];
```

if it's an `IEnumerable<string>`,

```
string beforeLast = null;
if (lsRelation != null) {
  int l_count = lsRelation.Count();
  if (l_count > 1)
     beforeLast = lsRelation.Skip(l_count - 2).Take(1);
}
```