# is there a simple shortcut to get the next to last item from an array?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a simple way to get the next to last item from an array? For example, I might have the following string arrays:

```
var myArr1 = new string[]{"S1", "S2", "S3"};
var myArr2 = new string[]{"S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"};
```

I need to write a generic routine which would return "S2.S3" for myArr1 and "S3.S4" for myArr2.  Getting then last item is easy enough with Last() but there doesn't appear to be a Last(-1) option.  Is there anything similar to this?  If not then what would be the easiest and most elegant way to do this?

Comment: `myArr[myArr.length - 2] +"." + myArr[myArr.length - 1]` - this should do!

Comment: $"{myArr1[myArr1.Length - 2]}.{myArr1.Last()}"

Comment: Here is a big question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3453274/5311735 (concentrates on using LINQ though).

Comment: You'll need to do some range checking on it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857137/how-to-find-second-last-element-from-a-list

Comment: Are you constrained to working with arrays? Arrays are fairly shonky to deal with and, unless you're implementing collection classes yourself, it's usually better to pick a collection class that (may) more directly support the operations you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure about efficiency but one other way is - myArr1.Reverse().ToArray()[1];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find second last element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857137/how-to-find-second-last-element-from-a-list)

Comment: Why are you asking this? Why not just access the last two items by index? Or use the (inefficient) `myArr1.Skip(myArr1.Length -2)` to skip all items except the last two?

Comment: I have created a nuget package with some extra LINQ-like operator methods for .NET collections (not usable with entity framework or the likes) that has what you need - https://github.com/lassevk/linqy - in this case it would be `string.Join(".", myArr1.Last(2))`, you can add it inside Visual Studio using the nuget package manager.

Comment: And what if your array contains one or less elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the second last element of an array using this code...

```
myArr1[myArr1.Length - 2]

myArr2[myArr2.Length - 2]
```

Output

```
S2    
S3
```

Online Demo: http://rextester.com/AERTN64718

***Updated...***

```
myArr1[myArr1.Length - 2] + "." + myArr1[myArr1.Length - 1]

myArr2[myArr2.Length - 2] + "." + myArr2[myArr2.Length - 1]
```

or

```
myArr1[myArr1.Length - 2] + "." + myArr1.Last()

myArr2[myArr2.Length - 2] + "." + myArr2.Last()
```

Output

```
S2.S3
S3.S4
```

Online Demo: http://rextester.com/DJU86580

Comment: um... that wasn't what they asked... they wanted the _last two elements_ of _one_ array. Not the second-to-last of two...

Comment: @Nyerguds, Thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is based of off @Ehsan's answer (which was in VB, but I translated it to C#)

```cs
string LastTwoStrings(string[] array)
{
    return (array[array.Length-2] + "." + array[array.Length-1]);
}
```

However, this WILL throw an exception if the array is smaller than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using System.Linq you could do:

```
String.Join(".", arr.Skip(arr.Length - 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your [C# version (8.0+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) you may also have access to an *unary expression* that counts the index in reverse from the current collection.
E.g. just like indexing from the front [0] to get 1st entry, you can get the the last entry by counting from the back [^1].

This is to be read like "length-1" of the current collection.

```
private readonly string[] _entries = new[]
{
   "Hello",
   "How's life?",
   "Likewise",
   "Bye"
};

public string GetLastEntry()
{
   return _entries[^1]; // Returns "Bye" and is the same as "_entries[_entries.Length-1]"
}
```

So for your particular example, you could just use **string.Join()** for the string-based use case, but let's try the reverse index. With those, we could output the last **n** entries like here:

```
private readonly string[] _entries = { "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4" };

public string GetTailingEntries(int depth)
{
    if (depth < 0 || depth > _entries.Length)
    {
        // Catch this however you require
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    string output = _entries[^depth--];
    while (depth > 0)
    {
        output += $".{_entries[^depth--]}";
    }

    return output;
}
```

Essentially we take any depth, let's take '2'  like in your question. It would initialize the output with the furthest entry from the end ([^2]) which is "S3" and decrement the depth, putting the next entry at [^1]. In the loop we append the values to the output until we reached our desired depth.

```
GetTailingEntries(2) // "S3" -> "S3.S4"
GetTailingEntries(4) // "S1" -> "S1.S2" -> "S1.S2.S3" -> "S1.S2.S3.S4"
```

Answer (score 0):

### With LINQ

This need is so basic and intuitive that I would consider writing my own `Last(int)` extension method-- exactly the one you'd imagine-- and it might look like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Last<T>(this IEnumerable<T> This, int count)
    {
        return This.Reverse().Take(count).Reverse();
    }
}
```

You can then get what you need with:

```
Console.WriteLine
(
    string.Join(".", myArr1.Last(2))
);
```

Which outputs:

```
S2.S3
```

### Using array (more efficient)

On the other hand, if you're looking for efficiency, you should just work with the array and the known indices, which will be more efficient that using `IEnumerable` (which will have to scan).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Last<T>(this T[] This, int count)
{
    var i = This.Length;
    if (count > i) count = i;
    while (count-- > 0) yield return This[--i];
}
```

...does exactly the same thing, but only for arrays.

Comment: `Take` only takes as long as there are elements, so it's 100% safe, but that last one could give out of range exceptions...

Comment: @Nyerguds Thanks, I added a boundary condition based on your feedback.